# How to get latest artifact created for a given branch using the Gitlab python API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab

Using [this request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts) it's possible to download the latest artifacts created in the Gitlab CI on a specific branch. For example:

```sh
curl "https://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTNAME/jobs/artifacts/MYBRANCH/download" \
  --data-urlencode "job=build"
```

How do I do the same thing using the Gitlab python API? [This page](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/builds.html?highlight=artifact#jobs) was all the documentation I could find, but it doesn't have a way of finding the latest job or artifact.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the latest GitLab artifact from a job using the `requests` library or `python-gitlab`. You'll need to setup the following environment variables:

- **GITLAB_TOKEN**: If you have a paid version of GitLab, you can use the built-in `CI_PROJECT_TOKEN` and use `PROJECT-TOKEN` instead of `PRIVATE-TOKEN` in the request header. Otherwise, add this as a masked variable.
- **CI_PROJECT_ID**: If you're running from a pipeline, you get this for free. Otherwise, you can find the ID under the title in the project home page in GitLab.

#### python-gitlab

To download a specific file from the latest job in a branch:

```py
import gitlab

project_id = os.getenv('CI_PROJECT_ID')     # built-in pipeline variable
gitlab_token = os.getenv('GITLAB_TOKEN')    # store in masked CI/CD variable
branch_name = 'master'
job_name = 'system-tests'

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.example.com', private_token=gitlab_token)
project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
raw_data = project.artifact(ref_name=branch_name, artifact_path='path/to/filename', job=job_name)
```

The API docs show some examples for writing the streamed data to file:
https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/pipelines_and_jobs.html#streaming-example

To download the artifact as a zip from a job, it will be simpler to just use the requests library.

#### requests

The code below downloads all artifacts of the job as a zip file. To download the contents of a single artifact file instead of the whole zip, simply replace `download` in the URL below with `raw/path/to/filename`

```py
import requests

project_id = os.getenv('CI_PROJECT_ID')     # built-in pipeline variable
gitlab_token = os.getenv('GITLAB_TOKEN')    # stored in masked CI/CD variable
branch_name = 'master'
job_name = 'system-tests'

url = f'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/jobs/artifacts/{branch_name}/download'
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': gitlab_token}
params = {'job': job_name}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)

# if artifact is a text file:
print(response.text)
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is if said job is not always part of the pipeline (eg: `only` if some files `changes`).
In such case the API endpoint fails to retrieve artifacts (since they are not part of the last successful pipeline) instead of looking for the last successful iteration of that particular job.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @DV82XL excellent answers:

**For Bash/curl**

```bash
GITLAB_TOKEN="SECRET"
PROJECT_ID=1234
BRANCH_NAME=master
JOB_NAME="some_job"

curl -o artifacts.zip --header "Private-Token: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" \
        "https://YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${BRANCH_NAME}/download?job=${JOB_NAME}"
```

If there's just a single file, you can unpack the file with:

```bash
curl  --header "Private-Token: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" \
        "https://YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${BRANCH_NAME}/download?job=${JOB_NAME}" \
    | bsdtar -xOf - > single-file.txt
```

**for ansible**

```yaml
- set_fact:
    gitlab_hostname: YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER
    gitlab_project_id: NN
    gitlab_branch_name: master
    gitlab_job_name: some-job
    gitlab_token: "secret-token"


- name: "download job artifact from {{gitlab_branch_name}} job {{gitlab_job_name}}"
  get_url:
    url: https://{{gitlab_hostname}}/api/v4/projects/{{gitlab_project_id}}/jobs/artifacts/{{gitlab_branch_name | urlencode}}/download?job={{gitlab_job_name | urlencode}}
    dest: /tmp/gitlab_artifact.zip
    headers:
      Private-Token: "{{gitlab_token}}"

- name: unpack to target location
  unarchive:
    src: /tmp/gitlab_artifact.zip
    dest: /target/folder
    include: file_name.txt
    remote_src: yes
  notify: restart some-service
```